# install qrencoder gem on osx for ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, installation

I am trying to install the qrencoder gem on my mac osx 10.7.4 to use in a ruby on rails project.

When I try gem install qrencoder here is what I get:

`ERROR:  Error installing qrencoder:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for qrencode.h... yes
    checking for QRinput_new() in -lqrencode... no
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.`

The mkmf.log file does not say anything other than the above.
I have qrencode-3.3.0 installed ok with brew but the gem install fails: any idea ?

when I type qrencode, here is what I get:

"dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libqrencode.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/qrencode
  Reason: Incompatible library version: qrencode requires version 7.0.0 or later, but libqrencode.3.dylib provides version 5.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5"

Answer (score 3):

First install libqrencode via homebrew:

```
  brew install qrencode
```

Then try installing the gem again:

```
  gem install qrencoder
```

There are more detailed instructions at https://github.com/harrisj/qrencoder if you don't have homebrew and/or would prefer to compile from source.

Comment: Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install qrencode libqrencode-dev`

Comment: brew install qrencode runs fine. The problem is with gem install qrencoder.

Answer (score 0):

To install qrencode on ubuntu 12.04 run the command:--

```
sudo apt-get install qrencode libqrencode-dev
```

Comment: My question was about OSX, not ubuntu.

Comment: yes, i have faced this problem on ubuntu and other solutions doesn't worked for me and this answer solved me, so i thought this may help others.